# How to update the item of a ComboBox

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have programmed a button that when clicking on **'+'** the new rows that are generated from the table should be updated with the previous comboBox selection, (the giff better illustrates the goal).

[image]

Based on the documentation I understand that it is done with the setCurrentIndex method, I applied it but I still can't get anything, please, any expert who can help me? thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QComboBox, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class subwindowDatosEntrada_Dinamic(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(subwindowDatosEntrada_Dinamic,self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Gui/subventanaDatosEntrada_Dinamic.ui', self)
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.ventanas[0] = 1
        self.parent.ventanas[1] = 1
        self.iniciar()         

        # Botones
        self.btn_mas.clicked.connect(self.mas)
        self.btn_menos.clicked.connect(self.menos)

    def iniciar(self):
        if len(self.parent.datos_generales[0]) > 0:
            for i in range(len(self.parent.datos_generales[0])):
                self.mas()
                self.table_datosEntrada.cellWidget(i, 1).setCurrentText(self.parent.datos_generales[0][i][1])
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.parent.datos_generales[0][i][2])))
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.parent.datos_generales[0][i][3])))
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(self.parent.datos_generales[0][i][4])))


    def mas(self): 
        nuevo = self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount() #--> Este método me cuenta filas para luego agregarlas.    
        self.table_datosEntrada.insertRow(nuevo)

        for row in range(self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount() - 1, self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount(), 1):
            for rowe in range(self.table_datosEntrada.columnCount()):

                c1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                c1.addItems(['Columna', 'Viga'])
                c1.setEditable(True) # Pasos para centrarComboBox
                c1.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
                c1.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                for i in range(c1.count()):
                    c1.setItemData(i, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)

                self.table_datosEntrada.setCellWidget(nuevo, rowe, c1)       

                if nuevo != 0:
                    last_index = self.table_datosEntrada.cellWidget(nuevo - 1, rowe).currentIndex()
                    c1.setCurrentIndex(last_index)

                rowe += 1
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                if nuevo != 0:
                    value = self.table_datosEntrada.item(nuevo-1, rowe).text()

                else:
                    value = 0
                item.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
                self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(nuevo, rowe, item)
```

Excuse my English, it is not my native language

Comment: If you want to set new items to a default index, just connect the `currentIndexChanged` of each new combobox to a function that stores the "new" default index, then always use that index with `setCurrentIndex` on new combo boxes. On a completely different matter, I understand that English is not your native language, but please avoid using variable names and comments in other languages: they only make your example much more difficult to read, which means that it will be harder for us to understand your code and then help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will take the suggestion into account, but could you please illustrate the explanation you give me with code to understand what you want to tell me, that is, from the code I sent you, what would you change? @musicamante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep track of the *latest* changed index of *any* combobox, and use that as the current index for any new QComboBox you create:

```
class subwindowDatosEntrada_Dinamic(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.defaultComboIndex = 0

    def setDefaultComboIndex(self, index):
        self.defaultComboIndex = index

    def mas(self): 
        # ...
                c1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                c1.addItems(['Columna', 'Viga'])
                c1.setCurrentIndex(self.defaultComboIndex)
                c1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.setDefaultComboIndex)
                # ...
```

A couple of really important suggestions:

1. always prefer Capitalized names for classes (**carefully** read the suggestions on the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), aka, PEP 8).
2. obviously, you can use any name styling convention on your programs; but when you're sharing code and asking for help with it, it's considered good practice (and politeness) to stick with code styling conventions and **always** use English language (for classes, variables, constants, functions, etc): people reading your code might use *other* native languages, meaning that the names you're using make no sense to them; their struggling with meaningless names will probably result in them giving up on trying to help you, leaving you without a possible answer to your doubts.

Comment: Ok, I will take your suggestions into account for the next occasion, thank you very much.